# Is it safe to perform select statements from a second program

Tags: python, sql, firebird

I'm really new to programming in general. I'm trying to self-learn some things in order to develop a few simple programs for the lab I work in. We are currently using a commercial software that generates and maintains a firebird database.

I am trying to develop a piece of software (Python 3.0 - Tkinter) that connects to the aforementioned database, performs a bunch of select statements (according to user instructions) and then stores some of the results (and some other data) in a different Firebird database.

I've chosen to create another database for storing these new data because I was afraid I could mess up the original database, which is critically important.

Now, I was wondering if what I'm doing could, in any way, compromise the original database stability and integrity. Both programs will be working on the same database simultaneously, though my program will only perform select statements.

Hope my question was clear, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Read-only access to a database greatly, greatly reduces the possibility of causing any issue with the database -- apart from performance issues of running multiple queries.

Comment: Great!! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only select from the database, or at least not modify tables  'owned' by the other program (or the data in those tables), then you should be good.

In Firebird with the usual transaction isolation levels, readers will not block writers. The only effect of performing selects from another program would be extra load on the database server, but unless you do crazy things (queries that require a lot of IO or other processing capacity) that should hardly be noticeable.

And if you use a read-committed read-only (`ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITED_RO`) transaction (see [Transaction Management](http://pythonhosted.org/fdb/usage-guide.html#transanction-management) in the FDB documentation), then it is even impossible for your program to modify the database. This option is FDB specific, if you use pyfirebirdsql, you need to look at [Advanced Transaction Control](https://pyfirebirdsql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/beyond-python-db-api.html#advanced-transaction-control) in the pyfirebirdsql documentation.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'll take your advice and look into Transaction Management.

Comment: in normal databases selecting is read-only operation, though in super-smartie databases there could be triggers, computed columns, views with SPs and anything. So, yeah, only read-only transactions. And if it is one time action then yet better just to backup the database and restore its clone to one's local computer and experiment with the clone.